# Automation process-Inserting a new teststep in a testcase

Tags: performance

I work for a product development team and the problem which i am facing is very specific to my team. As I am not able to come up with any solution, so i am asking it here.

Scenario: In my testcase, there are three folders - actual, expected & res.

In expected folder, i have recordings having expected response(freezed before running the testcase) which has following nomenclature-2_3_1_2_open_bam.sym
where

1st digit represents that recording (.sym file) belongs to 2nd teststep of the testcase.

2nd digit- no of iterations for the test step.

3rd digit- recording no.

4th digit- no. of iterations of the recording.

In my actual folder, recordings with the similar nomenclature is present, but it contains recording which are generated after running a testcase (actual response).

In my res folder, recording showing any difference between the actual and expected is present. (same nomenclature)

Whenever i run my testcase, comparison between the respective recordings in the actual and expected is done. Any difference between the recording gets saved in res folder.

So the problem which i am facing is-whenever i insert a new step between any 2 existing teststep, after running a testcase, new sym files are generated in actual folder with the nomenclature. But in expected folder, previous recording remains the same. Hence the comparisons fail-for eg. 2_1_4_1.sym missing message is generated. Currently, I have to redo all the previous steps whenever i have to insert a new teststep.

for eg.:
I have the following recordings in my

Expected folder (freezed before as expected response is already known):

1_1_1_1_open_assortment.sym

1_1_2_1_selectscope.sym

1_1_3_1_filterscope.sym

2_1_4_1_plancc.sym

2_1_4_2_plan1cc.sym

2_1_5_1_close_assortment.sym

in ACTUAL folder (after running testcase):

1_1_1_1_open_assortment.sym

1_1_2_1_selectscope.sym

1_1_3_1_filterscope.sym

2_1_4_1_plancc.sym

2_1_4_2_plan1cc.sym

2_1_5_1_close_assortment.sym

No missing files error after comparison as all corresponding recordings are present in both actual and expected folder.

NOW if i insert a new teststep( with 3 recordings) for example between 1 & 2 in the testcase, and when i run the testcase,

actual folder will have these following recordings now:

1_1_1_1_open_assortment.sym

1_1_2_1_selectscope.sym

1_1_3_1_filterscope.sym

2_1_4_1_newrecording.sym

2_1_5_1_newrecording.sym

2_1_6_1_newrecording.sym

3_1_7_1_plancc.sym

3_1_8_1_plan1cc.sym

3_1_8_1_closeassortment.sym

So when comparison is done now on running the testcase, following files will be missing:
2_1_4_1_newrecording.sym

2_1_5_1_newrecording.sym

2_1_6_1_newrecording.sym

3_1_7_1_plancc.sym

3_1_8_1_plan1cc.sym

3_1_8_1_closeassortment.sym

as they are not present in the expected folder. So user has to redo all the steps again in the expected folder and change the nomenclature for every recording after inserting a new teststep in between 2 teststeps.

Please suggest me some nomenclature, so that a user doesn't have to re-do all the steps again in expected folder manually. I hope you understand my problem. Also please dont hesitate to ask me for any clarifications.

Thanks, any help would be highly appreciated.